# How do I make a column that compares whether the entry in the one column matches the entry in another?

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, textjoin

I'm working on this excel problem and I ran into an issue I'm not sure how to solve.

In my Google Sheets document, column A shows all the customers that placed an order in August, while column B shows all the customers that placed an order in September. I need column C to look at all the values in August and all the values in September and if there is a match to return "retained customer" and if there isn't to return "new customer". I have tried combining the if and vlookup function, in something like `=if(vlookup(B1,A:A,1,False), 'retained cusomer', 'new cusomer')`, but I keep getting an error.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I can do to fix it? Thank you so much!

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Kindly add input table and expected output table as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(REGEXMATCH(B:B; TEXTJOIN("|"; 1; A:A)); "retained customer"; "new customer"))
```